# Detect Centre of Target in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, detection

Can anyone suggest alternative means of detecting the centre of each of the targets in the following image using MATLBAB:

[image: Targets]

My current approach uses regionprops and centroid detection.

```
clc,  clear all, close all
format long
beep off
rng('default')

I=imread('WP_20160811_13_38_26_Pro.jpg');


BW=im2bw(I);
BW=imcomplement(BW);

s  = regionprops(BW, 'area','Centroid');

centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
imshow(BW)
hold on
plot(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'b*')
hold off
```

Is there a more precise way of detecting the centre as this approach seems sensitive to noise, perspective distortion, etc. Is there a way to find the intersection of each of the two quarter circles.

Another type of target I am considering is: [image]
Can anyone suggest a way for detecting the centre of a crosshair?  Thanks

Comment: If you say that this approach is sensitive to noise try denoising the image before you do your processing.

Comment: I have not used Matlab, but I think it might be possible using HoughCircles method, performed in this function [HERE](http://se.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html). Circles in your image are incomplete, but with properly denoised and processed input image and right parameters it might give you the coordinates of circles.

Comment: I agree that the Hough transform is worth trying, even if the circles aren't complete. The downside is that you won't be able to generalize this to genetic shapes, but it might work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My modification works 100% efficient for your image:

```
I = imadjust(imcomplement(rgb2gray(imread('WP_20160811_13_38_26_Pro.jpg'))));
filtered_BW = bwareaopen(im2bw(I), 500, 4);
% 500 is the area of ignored objects

final_BW = imdilate(filtered_BW, strel('disk', 5));

s  = regionprops(final_BW, 'area','Centroid');
centroids = cat(1, s([s.Area] < 10000).Centroid);
% the condition leaves out the big areas on both sides

figure; imshow(final_BW)
hold on
plot(centroids(:,1), centroids(:,2), 'b*')
hold off
```

[image]

The functions I am adding:

- `rgb2gray` to have one dimension of values!
- `imadjust` to automatically optimize the brightness and contrast,
- `bwareaopen` to get rid of small islands,
- `imdilate` and `strel` to grow the regions and connect disconnected regions.